# How Sentinel Hub's get image by specific date works

Tags: python, sentinel-2, sentinel-hub

I know how to specify date, when creating request in Sentinel Hub. But some areas come back as just black or white polygons. Does it mean that SH does not have images for those dates? And if it does not, how do I request latest existing image. Also, when time range is more than one day, how is this image constructed? Feel free to send me back to official docs in case I missed something.

P.S. I am using Sentinel-2-L2A, making requests via Requests Builder web interface and also Python package `sentinelhub`.